# Get data from .repository file with python

Tags: python-3.x

```
username = abc@gmail.com
password = abc@123
```

> Want to get username value if I give the username as the key.

Comment: Did you try by using python dictionary?

Comment: @Prabhakar I think python dict is used for store data but I want to get data from a .repository file.